# setup.py install vs pip install

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-3.8

I want to create a python package which will be cloned from its git repo when a build runs, so I will have the source inside the build agent. I would then like to run the python package as a command line tool, the package is called `environment_manager`.

Initially I thought I would follow a tutorial for creating a simple `setup.py` although this has proved to be a lot more difficult than I thought it would be and whenever I run `python setup.py install --force` I am not able to use my installed package, generally either module not found or the command is not recognised when I type it.

I have found that if I simply install with `pip install .` then I am actually able to use the tool from the command line and it works. I don't understand what the difference is, or why this only works when doing the pip install method.

Below is the `setup.py` file, I cannot see what is wrong with it:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, find_namespace_packages
import pathlib

here = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

# Get the long description from the README file
long_description = (here / 'README.MD').read_text(encoding='utf-8')

setup(
    name='environment_manager',
    version='1.0.0',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src', include='environment_manager.*'),
    python_requires='>=3.8, <4',
    install_requires=['boto3', 'botocore', 'pyyaml'],
    extras_require={
        'dev': ['pre-commit', 'black', 'pylint'],
        'test': ['pytest', 'pytest-mock', 'coverage'],
    },
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'environment-manager=environment_manager.environment_controller:main',
        ],
    }
)
```

My project structure looks like:

```
environment_manager
   /src
      conf/
      environment_manager/
         environment_controller.py
         config_parser.py
         command.py
      test/
         unit_tests.py
```

I thought the correct way to install and run the tool from the command line was to use `setup.py` and `setuptools` but it seems like it is a lot easier and actually works if I just install it with pip.

Is installing it with `pip` over `setup.py` correct (as both ways the package appears when I type `pip list`) and are there any issues with my `setup.py` script? The script was taken from the pypa sample project and I removed most of what I didnt need.

Answer (score 5):

**setup.py** is a python file, which usually tells you that the module/package you are about to install has been packaged and distributed with Distutils, which is the standard for distributing Python Modules. This allows you to easily install Python packages. Often it's enough to write: `$ pip install .`

---

In other words **setup.py** is a packaging file while **pip** is a package manager, therefore you should have **setup.py** file to be able to install with **pip**.

Comment: So in theory installing both ways should work? I have spent hours trying to work out why installing the way setuptools recommends doesnt work, and found out that installing with pipe does work.

Comment: My problem is in a tiny debian container pip drags in 385MB, while python3 + python3-requests and python3-setuptools uses 48MB. but I need the `pip install -e .` to address the packages in my module.

Answer (score 3):

`pip` is a package manager which helps install, manage, and uninstall Python packages. It searches for them on PyPI, downloads them, and then runs their `setup.py` script.

Since you mentioned that you can run your binary executable after a `pip` install, but not a `setup.py` install, it is likely that each of them is installing the binary to separate locations.

One thing I would check is that you are using `python` and `pip` from the same version of Python, e.g:

```
% python --version
Python 3.8.6
% pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

If these have different Python versions listed, they are likely installing to two separate directories - one in your `PATH` environment variable, and one which is not.

Next, I would check `pip list -v` after each install method, as this should list a `Location` header telling you where the package has been installed.

Comment: In both circumstances I am installing into a virtual environment created using pyenv, the only difference being I run `pip install` or python `setup.py install`, pip and python appear like `/home/user1/.pyenv/shims/python` and `/home/user1/.pyenv/shims/pip` so I assumed (but probably wrong) that it should be working the same either way?

Comment: If I look at the `environment-manager` location it looks like `/home/paul/.pyenv/shims/environment-manager` if installed using`pip`, and with setuptool it returns nothing. However `pip list` returns the same thing either way `environment-manager 1.0.0`. If i try to run it when installed with `setup.py` I get `bash: /home/user1/.pyenv/shims/environment-manager: No such file or directory`

Comment: @berimbolo You mentioned that you see it in `pip list` with both install methods. If you pass `pip list -v` it'll tell you where the Package is installed. Maybe try this after each install method?

Comment: Ok, so with the `setup.py` it installs to /home/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/environment_manager/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environment_manager-1.0.0-py3.8.egg and if I install it with `pip` it is installed to `/home/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/environment_manager/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, so almost the same yet only the `pip` install works. Does this give away any information to you? Adding the `-v` is very helpful.

Comment: I think you might be right but I am not sure exactly what the issue is, I am actually able to get the same error if I do `python -m pip install .`, I still really dont understand what is happening but the path is still `/home/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/environment_manager/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, however installing it using `pip` as a python *module* gives the same error as running the `setup.py` script directly: `bash: /home/user1/.pyenv/shims/environment-manager: No such file or directory`

Comment: @berimbolo To be honest, I am starting to think this may be related to `pyenv` environmental configuration, and you might have luck reaching out to the pyenv community? It's not a tool I am familiar with unfortunately.